B-Spline basis on a 3D mesh
I need to interpolate some (sparse) data scattered on a 3D manifold mesh. In other words, I have a scattered interpolation problem where the input values are defined for some vertices of the mesh. Apparently this is known as the surface-on-surface interpolation problem in the literature.
I have used in the past the penalized or P-Splines of Marx and Eilers for a similar problem with very good results, so I am trying to find a way to use these techniques for the new problem. Please notice that the mesh is given and never changes, in other words this is not a mesh refinement or mesh interpolation problem.
It seems that the main obstacle that I need to overcome to bring all this into the P-spline framework is the construction of a B-spline basis on the triangular mesh. The literature on splines is overwhelming and I have not found yet a clear candidate for this problem. Any pointer to such an algorithm will be greatly appreciated!
